# List <li> element not hiding even after calling .hide() on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The html code is

```
 <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="faqNav"><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="loginNav"><a href="#loginModal1" data-toggle="modal">Log In</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav1" class="visible-xs-block"><a href="profile.php">Account</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav2"  class="visible-xs-block nested"><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav3" class="visible-xs-block nested" id="logoutNav" onclick="logout()"><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The jquery code is

```
 $('#accountNavX' ).hide();
```

This has not worked.My end goal is to only hide all the account nav list items.

Edit:

Was lazy accountNavX was referring to me repeating it three times with the respective number.

Comment: Where is `accountNavX`? I can't see this ID. I think, you should try `$(".visible-xs-block").hide()`

Comment: or can try `$( "li[id^='accountNav']" ).hide();`

Comment: follow the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to understand the use of selectors for reference.

Comment: only on mobile? What browser? Maybe you have an older mobile browser that isn't compatible with jquery?

Comment: How to passing X value?

Comment: Do you realize that one of those divs has two separate ids (accountNav3 and logoutNav)?  That isn't valid.  Also, you need to post what visible-xs-block and nested classes do because if either of those have a display attribute with !important, calling .hide isn't going to do anything.

Comment: @RobertMcKee `visible-xs-block` is from Bootstrap, and it does have `!important`. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery hides by writing `display:none` directly on the element. Usually it takes precedence over all. Bootstrap attaches `!important` to it's `display: block` code, thus preventing jquery from overriding it.

You would have to do the following:

```
$('.accountNavX').removeClass('visible-xs-block').hide();
```

Comment: Thank you. Thanks for the insight on bootstrap force attaching a !important. This worked.

Comment: Is it hide all three items ?

Comment: @GovindSamrow the idea is you do it three times manually replacing 1,2,3 for `X`

Answer (score 1):

In below code snippet, I have added a class `acc-nav`. I am using that to hide elements.

Or you can use a different selector like `li[id^=accountNav]`.

```js
function hideNavItems() {
  // $('.acc-nav').hide()
  $("li[id^=accountNav]").hide()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="faqNav"><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="loginNav"><a href="#loginModal1" data-toggle="modal">Log In</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav1" class="acc-nav visible-xs-block"><a href="profile.php">Account</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav2" class="acc-nav visible-xs-block nested"><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav3" class="acc-nav visible-xs-block nested" id="logoutNav" onclick="logout()"><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>

  <button onclick="hideNavItems()">Hide Account Nav items</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('[id^=accountNav]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="faqNav"><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="loginNav"><a href="#loginModal1" data-toggle="modal">Log In</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav1" class="visible-xs-block"><a href="profile.php">Account</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav2" class="visible-xs-block nested"><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav3" class="visible-xs-block nested" id="logoutNav" onclick="logout()"><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@f.khantsis answer is correct.

Here's my solution in CSS way. You can use media query to hide certain elements in smaller break points,

```
@media (max-width: 767px){

  #accountNav1, #accountNav2, #accountNav3{
     display: none !imporant;
  }

}
```

This way you don't need to worry for larger screen which button will appear automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new class to all the accountNav-id- items. For example add a class called accountNav to all of those. Then just call $(".accountNav").hide();

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="faqNav"><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="loginNav"><a href="#loginModal1" data-toggle="modal">Log In</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav1" class="visible-xs-block"><a href="profile.php">Account</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav2"  class="visible-xs-block nested"><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
    <li id="accountNav3" class="visible-xs-block nested" id="logoutNav" onclick="logout()"><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and js code:

```
function logout(){
    $('.nav').children().hide();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to hide all the list item just the ones that have accountNav